# Hide and show parents and child menubar

Tags: jquery

I am trying to making a menubar. When someone clicks on parent li ( showul) i want to slidedown child li (hideul). and again when someone clicks on another parent li, it should open the respective child li as well as hide all the previously opened li. check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/topu119/2630my45/) for better understanding. Kindly help. I am learning jQUery.

```
<ul>   
  <li><a href="#" id="update" class="showul">Update Pages</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="category" class="showul">Category Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>Add Category</li>
      <li>Category List</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="postoption" class="showul">Post Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
     <li>Add Post</li>
     <li>Post List</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>


$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".showul").click(function(){
        $(".hideul").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use `siblings()` to find the `ul` related to the current `a`. Then to hide all the other `ul` while toggling the current one, you can use this:

```
$(".showul").click(function() {
    var $hideUl = $(this).siblings(".hideul");
    var show = !$hideUl.is(':visible');
    $('.hideul').slideUp('slow');
    if (show)
        $hideUl.slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**Update fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2630my45/2/)

Comment: This one is more perfect for me... Thanks Mr. Rory

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".showul").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".hideul").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>   
  <li><a href="#" id="update" class="showul">Update Pages</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="category" class="showul">Category Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>Add Category</li>
      <li>Category List</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="postoption" class="showul">Post Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
     <li>Add Post</li>
     <li>Post List</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".showul").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".hideul").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>   
  <li><a href="#" id="update" class="showul">Update Pages</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="category" class="showul">Category Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>Add Category</li>
      <li>Category List</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="postoption" class="showul">Post Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
     <li>Add Post</li>
     <li>Post List</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

1. To find the ul you need to go to parent of anchor then find the ul
2. You can also use `.siblings()`

Comment: @Nazmul glad it works i added an alternative.. Using `.siblings()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".showul").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".hideul").slideToggle("slow"); // get the next element of anchor tag and toggle it
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="title">Title & Slogan</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="social">Social Media</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="copyright">Copyright</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="update" class="showul">Update Pages</a>
       <ul class="hideul">
         <li>About Us</li>
         <li>Contact Us</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" id="category" class="showul">Category Option</a>
       <ul class="hideul">
         <li>Add Category</li>
         <li>Category List</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   <li><a href="#" id="postoption" class="showul">Post Option</a>
     <ul class="hideul">
       <li>Add Post</li>
       <li>Post List</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".showul").click(function(){
    console.log("here")
    $(this).next(".hideul").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `slideUp()` - to hide others and `slideToggle()` - to toggle state of current elements.

Also, use `:visible` selector to further reduce results from the query.

```
$(".showul").click(function(){
    var $currEl = $(this).next('.hideul');
    $(".hideul:visible").not($currEl).slideUp("slow");
    $currEl.slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2630my45/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps you have to go through.

1. Hiding all the previously opened blocks
2. Showing the wanted block

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".showul").click(function(){
    $(".hideul").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).parent().find(".hideul").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>   
  <li><a href="#" id="update" class="showul">Update Pages</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="category" class="showul">Category Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
      <li>Add Category</li>
      <li>Category List</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="postoption" class="showul">Post Option</a>
    <ul class="hideul">
     <li>Add Post</li>
     <li>Post List</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```